# what's the difference between output_graph.pb and saved_model.pb in tensorflow inception v3

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow to train inception v3, and I get two different output files, the one is output_graph.pb and the other saved_model.pb. I checked some pages about the difference between them, but I didn't really get it. Is there any one who can explain it to me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is not clear in the documentation about saved model?